# Time histogram in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to consolidate the info in the following table in intervals of 1 day, for all columns, counting the number of uuids in each interval

```
uuid   days_to_signup    days_to_doc_submission1 
 1         1,5                     3
 2         2,5                     5
 3         3,2                     3,6
 4         0,5                     4,2
 5         200                     250
```

I want to have a table like this:

```
time count(days_to_signup)   count(days_to_doc_submission1)
 0-1         1                    0
 1-2         1                    0
 2-3         1                    0
 3-4         1                    2
 4-5         0                    1
  ...
 200-201     1                    0
 201-202     0                    0
 ...
 250-251     0                    1
```

The big problem here is to do it without defining multiple clauses of case when. The number of days can be as huge as 2 years (730 days).

However, I think that knowing hw to do this in a more general way (different intervals, for instance). Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.  I actually think this is a somewhat interesting question.

Comment: And I have looked for hours in the internet for an answer and was not able to find it. Thanks Gordon

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I didn't down-vote, but I can imagine others may have because there is no information about any attempts and no SQL posted. I know I am much more inclined to help when I see that they put forth the effort to at least try to reach a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select gs.t,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where t.days_to_signup >= t and t.days_to_signup < t + 1
       ) as count_dts,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where t.days_to_doc_submission1 >= t and t.days_to_doc_submission1 < t + 1
       ) as count_dds
from generate_series(0, 251, 1) as gs(t)
order by gs.t;
```

`generate_series()` is a built-in function in Postgres that generates a series of numbers or dates.  This gives you the rows you want.  The actual counts are done using correlated subqueries.

There are alternative approaches but this seemed like the simplest.

A more efficient method would be:

```
with x as (
      select days_to_signup as days, 1 as dts, 0 as dss
      from t
      union all
      select days_to_doc_submission1, 0, 1
      from t
     )
select gs.t, coalesce(sum(dts), 0) as dts, coalesce(sum(dss), 0) as dss
from generate_series(0, 251, 1) gs(t) left join
     x
     on x.days >= gs.t and
        x.days < gs.t
group by gs.t
order by gs.t;
```

Comment: Gordon, I receved this message:
"Only relations and subqueries are allowed in the FROM clause"

Do you know what this could mean?

Comment: @FláviodeFalcão . . . What version of Postgres are you using?  `generate_series()` definitely works in the `FROM` clause:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f5f16db64416f31dda3eb28677447dda.